# How we can get the total number of neurons from a model in Keras? Is there any function?

Tags: tf.keras

How can I get the total number of neurons from a deep learning model? Is there any function in Keras?

Comment: Try `print(model.summary())` when you use keras.

Comment: but it only has hyper parameters not the total number of neurons. Right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **layer output shapes** to count the number of neurons in a Keras model. If you multiply output dimensions of a layer, you can achieve the number of neurons in that layer. When you apply this to all valid layers (layers that have neurons) and sum the neuron counts, eventually you will get the total number of neurons in a Keras model. Here is the code:

```py
def get_total_number_of_neurons(model, include_output_layer):
    '''
    Args:
        model: Keras model
        include_output_layer: A boolean parameter. Whether or not to include output layer's neurons into the calculation

    Returns: number of neurons in the given model
    '''
    num_layers = len(model.layers)
    total_num_of_neurons = 0
    for layer_index in range(num_layers):
        layer = model.layers[layer_index]
        # since we multiply layer output dimensions, initial value is set to 1.
        num_neurons_in_layer = 1
        for i in range(1, len(layer.output.shape)):
            try:
                # when it is a valid layer to count neurons, an output dimension of the layer can be convertible to int.
                num_neurons_in_layer *= int(layer.output.shape[i])
            except Exception:
                # if the output dimension of layer cannot be convertible to int,
                # just pass that layer since it is not a valid layer to count neurons
                pass
        # if num_neurons_in_layer is not still 1, it means we have a valid layer to count neurons
        if not num_neurons_in_layer == 1:
            # when it is an output layer
            if layer_index == (num_layers - 1):
                if include_output_layer:
                    total_num_of_neurons += num_neurons_in_layer
            else:  # when it is not an output layer
                total_num_of_neurons += num_neurons_in_layer
    return total_num_of_neurons
```

I started multiplying the output dimesions from the second dimesion as it can be seen in the following part:

```
range(1, len(layer.output.shape))
```

The reason is that the first dimension of a layer output, is "**?**" which represents the number of samples you fed into the model and it's not related to number of neurons in the model. Hence, we skip the first dimension for the number of neurons calculation.

I also added a boolean parameter **include_output_layer** such that you can choose whether or not to include the output layer, in the number of neurons calculation.

Finally, you can call the function like this if you don't want to include the output layer:

```py
num_neurons = get_total_number_of_neurons(model= your_keras_model, include_output_layer= False)
```

Or, you can include the output layer in the calculation:

```py
num_neurons = get_total_number_of_neurons(model= your_keras_model, include_output_layer= True)
```

Hope this helps!